# FaceTime on MacBook: block unknown caller

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, facetime

I have a MacBook with High Sierra and would like to set FaceTime either so that only people in my contact list can call me or so that I can block individual people - even those who are not in my contacts.

Is that possible? Under FaceTime / Settings there is the *Blocked* (or similar, I'm translating from German) tab. There is also a phone number in it, but when I try to add more numbers or email addresses, my contacts open. But I don't want to have to create (fake) contacts for unknown callers just to be able to block them.

One specific person is already blocked on my iPhone, but this does not affect the MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of blocked numbers that I can see in my FT settings on my Mac reflects the phone numbers that I've blocked on my actual phone.  On both the phone and the Mac, trying to add more blocked numbers requires me to have a contact already created.

So, you have 2 choices:

1. Find the numbers you want to block in your phone's call history and block them there.  (Or wait until they call again, then block them.)
2. Create a new contact called "Blocked Numbers" or something, add ALL the numbers you know you want to block into that contact, and then add that Contact to your Blocked list.

Comment: I can block callers without creating a contact on my iPhone. It is on iOS 13.3, and I can block numbers after tapping on the *info* button next to any entry in the call list. The button opens a new view, and at the very bottom I can (un)block the caller.

However, what I took from your answer is the insight I can add any number of email addresses and phone numbers I want to block to a single contact. That's ok for me.